# Responsive menu viewport height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added a menu to my responsive website that pops up as soon as the viewport is 714px width or less.

When you click the button a menu slides out from the side across the page. The issue that I can't seem to solve is that I want the menu to be the height of the current viewport without allowing people to scroll down.

Here's a fiddly of what the menu looks like right now:
https://jsfiddle.net/baqcfjt1/1/

```
<div class="site-container-menu">
  <div class="site-pusher">
    <header class="header">

      <a href="#" class="header__icon" id="header__icon">MENU</a>

      <nav class="menu">
        <a href="#one" class="scrolly">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#three" class="scrolly"><strong>Link 2</strong></a>
        <a href="#two" class="scrolly">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#four">Link 4</a>
      </nav>

    </header>
    <div class="site-content">
      <div class="container-menu">
        <section id="header">
          <div class="headerlogo"><img src="image" /></div>
          <div class="headerlogosmall"><img src="image" /></div>
        </section>

        <section class="main">
          -content-
        </section>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-cache" id="site-cache"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
  z-index: -10;
  position: absolute;
}


/* RESPONSIVE */

@media only screen and (max-width: 714px) {
  .container-menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  /* HEADER */
  .header__logo {
    font: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0 25px;
    float: left;
  }
  /* MENU */
  .site-pusher,
  .site-container-menu {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .site-container-menu {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .site-pusher {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  .site-content {}
  .header {
    position: static;
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 62px;
    color: rgba(228, 91, 65, 1.00);
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .header__icon {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3em;
    font: inherit;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 66px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .header__icon:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 0;
    top: 16px;
    left: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px rgba(228, 91, 65, 1.00), 0 16px 0 1px rgba(228, 91, 65, 1.00), 0 22px 0 1px rgba(228, 91, 65, 1.00);
  }
  .menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    /*    overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;*/
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-250px);
    transform: translateX(-250px);
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    color: #666666;
    height: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  }
  .menu a:hover {
    color: #e45b41;
  }
  .with--sidebar .site-pusher {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
    transform: translateX(250px);
  }
  .with--sidebar .site-cache {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: 9999;
  }
}

    $(document).ready(function() {

  (function($) {

    $('#header__icon').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('body').toggleClass('with--sidebar');
    });

    $('#site-cache').click(function(e) {
      $('body').removeClass('with--sidebar');
    });

  })(jQuery);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using viewport-percentage length units: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

One option would be to use the `vh` css unit and specify that the `body` has `height:100vh`

https://jsfiddle.net/r61n4y0v/

I added:

```
body{
  height:100vh;
}
```

to the CSS file.

You should also check the `vh` unit's browser compatibility, before using it. You can check here:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

---

If you'd like to be more specific with the `height:100vh;` rule, you can remove the `overflow:hidden` from `.site-container-menu` and add `height:100vh` to `.menu` directly:

https://jsfiddle.net/6won6stx/

Your menu links have both a height defined `height:25%` and padding...this is not advised as it can lead to unexpected behaviour. It would be better to replace:

```
<nav class="menu">
   <a href="#one" class="scrolly">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#three" class="scrolly"><strong>Link 2</strong></a>
   <a href="#two" class="scrolly">Link 3</a>
   <a href="#four">Link 4</a>
</nav>
```

With:

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#one" class="scrolly">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three" class="scrolly"><strong>Link 2</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#two" class="scrolly">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and remove the `height:25%` from the `a` element and add `height:25vh` to the `li` elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/s5gbk7y1/

I've also made a few other changes such as changing the `line-height` property on the menu links to `25vh`.

Take a look at the latest fiddle and let me know if it helps!

Comment: Yeah but the website should be scrollable when the menu isn't opened.

Comment: @Narc - I've just updated my answer, let me know how it looks.

Comment: @Narc - More updates, I think this is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/s5gbk7y1/

Comment: The height of the links is perfect now, thanks. The only issue that still remains is that the page is scrollable once the menu is opened. As I'm writing this though, I am thinking of making the menu fixed so that the page is scrollable but the menu stays the same. I'll check out how that looks and then report back here.

Comment: @Narc - Good, glad it helped. You may have issues making the menu fixed in Webkit browsers (Chrome) because of an issue with the `transform` css rule. I recommend either using different css to manage the sliding menu (maybe a minus margin, it will remove the need for `transform`) or as a worst case scenario, you could use JavaScript to mimic a fixed menu (but this is worst case).

Comment: It is only to be used on phone devices though, the slide out menu only appears on viewports of 714 width or less. Browsers and other devices with a viewport wider than 714 pixels will see a normal navbar without any fancy transform css rules. For some reason though I can't make the menu fixed, am I wrong to assume that the <ul> element needs to have its position set to fixed?

Comment: @Narc - I would add the fixed positioning to `.menu` but yeah, you're going to have issues because you're using `transform` on `.menu` and `.site-pusher`. This will give sub-elements a fixed position based on the element with the `transform` property...not the viewport. To correct this, try replacing the `transform` rules with other rules (such as changing the `left` or `margin-left` properties). You don't need to use `transform` to create a sliding menu, `left` or `margin-left` manipulation works just as well. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: @Narc - but if you continue having issues, I recommend accepting the answer above (since it solves your original question) and creating a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133598/discussion-between-narc-and-alvin-pascoe).